# Equivalent of hash_map::resize() in c++11's unordered_map

Tags: c++11, hashmap, unordered-map

What is equivalent of `hash_map::resize(n)` in c++11's `unordered_map`? Earlier resize of hash_map used to support: `void resize(size_type n)` that increases the bucket count to at least n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent is [rehash](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/rehash/):

```
Sets the number of buckets in the container to n or more.
```

rehash specify number of buckets, while reserve as in [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/reserve/):

> Sets the number of buckets in the container (bucket_count) to the most appropriate to contain at least n elements..

In SGI docs for [hash_map::resize](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) I have read that it changes number of buckets so IMO rehash is appropriate. But hash_map is not standard so various implementations may implement it differently.

Another thing is that reserve is actually implemented using rehash, in gcc 5.3 it looks as follows:

```
  void
  reserve(std::size_t __n)
  {
__hashtable* __this = static_cast<__hashtable*>(this);
__this->rehash(__builtin_ceil(__n / max_load_factor()));
  }
```

Comment: What is the difference of rehash and reserve?

Comment: `rehash` specify number of buckets, while reserve as in docs: `Sets the number of buckets in the container (bucket_count) to the most appropriate to contain at least n elements.`.  In SGI docs for hash_map::resize I have read that it changes number of buckets so IMO rehash is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rehash` to change the number of buckets.

Use `reserve` to accomodate the number of buckets in relationship to the *load factor* of the hash table. From the [docs of reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve):

> Effectively calls `rehash(std::ceil(count / max_load_factor()))`.